# C++ - Stl - map to int table

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, stl

I just started to learn C++ and I'm now programming a simple program able to read a log file ( Apache for example) and to give some information, but I'm stuck using a map to store data.
I'm using a map of a map, like that :

```
typedef map<string, int[25]> ReferTimes;
map <string, ReferTimes> myMap;
```

What I need is to access into the table `int[25]` (initialized with 0 for each case ) and to increment the value of a single case depending on the value of a given parameter. Each case corresponds to a slice of time (first case = 00 to 01, second case = 01 to 02 ... penultimate case = 23 to 24) but the last, that is the addition of previous cases (to count how much times a page have been clicked).

The string of ReferTimes corresponds to an internet page from which the user required another page, that is the key of myMap.

So : I associated to each required page every page from where the user had required it, and I associated to them the tables to know when and how much times one page have been clicked.

My problem is that I'm not able to access into these tables to change their values. Could you give me a little help?

I know it's not well explained, but I hope you can help me!

Comment: How did you tried to modify their values?

Comment: I tried something like myMap.insert(make_pair("exemple1", make_pair("exemple2", int[25])) but obviously It doesn't work. I'll try using a vector (only to add).
To modify values I don't have any idea of how to access to this vector, to change a value of a single case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First - fixing the code

First and most important: **You can't store simple arrays in STL containers**. You can however store a `std::vector` or a **pointer** to an array (or a plain pointer).

So, in order to be able to do anything, you need to change the definition of `ReferTimes` to be: `typedef map<string, int(*)[25]> ReferTimes;`.

Then, when you have your array (lets say `int someArray[]={0,1,2,...,24};`), and you want it to be under *string1->string2->data*, you do `myMap[string1][string2] = &someArray;`.

**Example:**
if your `myMap` has elements called *"ele1"*, *"ele2"* and *"ele3"*, and *"ele2"* consists of pairs *("first",&array1)*, *("second",&array2)* and *("third",&array3)*, in order to get the contents of *array3*, and write them down, you would do:

```
for(unsigned int i=0;i<25;i++)
    std::cout << myMap["ele2"]["third"][i];
```

### Second - handling the map as a whole

If you want to be able to view the whole contents of a `map`, you need to define an `iterator`. You can read about iterators on the [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/BidirectionalIterator/) page. In your case the iterator to `myMap` is:

```
map<string, ReferTimes>::iterator myMapIterator;
```

And to the "inner" map, it's:

```
ReferTimes::iterator referTimesIterator;
```

You can view all arrays by doing:

```
myMapIterator = myMap.begin();
for(;myMapIterator != myMap.end();myMapIterator++){
   cout << myMapIterator->first << endl;
   referTimesIterator = myMapIterator->second.begin();
   for(;referTimesIterator != myMapIterator->second.end(); referTimesIterator++){
      cout << "\t" << referTimesIterator->first << endl << "\t\t";
      for(unsigned int i=0;i<25;i++)
          cout << (*referTimesIterator->second)[i] << " ";
      cout << endl;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Pawel and thank you for the answer!
Ok, this seems to work, but what I need is a little different. How can I now access to this array "someArray" to change a value of a single case? 
I need to do this : someArray[i] = someArray[i] + 1 for a given couple.
Exemple : 

    bool addStore( string VisPage, string FromPage, int time ){
    ...
    myMap[ VisPage, FromPage ] = &someArray; //And I need to change this case : someArray[ time ] = someArray[ time ] + 1;
    ...
    }
Thank you!

Comment: Like I said - you just access the array by doing `myMap[VisPage][FromPage][time]` and just invoke `operator++` on the element. It should work. So the answer is: `myMap[VisPage][FromPage][time]++`. **Note**: The notation is independent from the array type. So no matter if you've chosen to use `vectors` or `pointers`, it'll be the same.

Comment: Thank you!It works!But I need another little help please.When I do myMap[VisPage][FromPage]=someArray and myMap[VisPage][FromPage][time]++, when I call the method for the second time, myMap[VisPage][FromPage]=someArray ll be wrong because the ++ will increment the same array of the first couple.
How can I affect a new 'someArray' (only if necessary) and to use the existing one for a couple that I already putted in my map?I miss the condition.It has to be like : if (the couple doesn't exists) -> use the initial array; else -> myMap[VisPage][FromPage][time]++
Thank you so much for your support!!

Comment: Well you need to create an different array for each entry. Or you can learn about dynamically allocating memory using the `new` operator. Then - when you need a new array, you'll just do `int* newArray = new int[25]`. if my comment really helped you - feel free to mark it as the answer :)

Comment: I've just done it using this condition : if(myMap[ VisPage ][FromPage] == NULL ) etc. and everything works perfectly!!!
Thaaaanks!!!:D